# Может ли быть подлежащим слово «княже»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, история, устаревшие-слова

Можно ли так написать:

— К тому же княже обещал лично озаботиться судьбой посланника.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В подавляющем большинстве случаев слово ***княже*** используется как обращение.
Думаю, что оно употреблялось в значении *господин, повелитель.*
О том, кто это, мимоходом сказано у [**Даля**](https://slovar.cc/rus/dal/550612.html):

**князь** — *стар.* **княж,** сокр. прилагается к отчеству, вместо сын. Князь Петр, княж Иванов, или княж Иванов сын.

Есть несколько источников, где нашлись предложения, в которых ***княже*** выступает в роли подлежащего:

*Молвил [**княже**](https://stihi.ru/2002/08/15-784) Святослав дружинникам:

«Гой еси, вы ясны мои соколы,

Да седлайте ж вы коней горячиих,

Да пойдём Путём, копьем указанным».*

*Многа славны справ сей [**княже**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ntEJDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT90&lpg=PT90&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB&source=bl&ots=KPKZxBFcu7&sig=FRE1rp21_0V2BQ_h955-xqohMc4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj63dCK0IXaAhXMJlAKHfK3AvcQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB&f=false) для русской земли совершивши и градов родны срубил многия.*
А. Гусаров. Из варяг в греки

*Наверное, **княже** Милорад был на хорошем счету у ваших богов, потому как случилось с ним чудо.

Говорили, что это чужие земли, неудачное место для строительства, да и людей мало в округе, ну и много других умных вещей. Но получилось все так, как сказал [**княже**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=JihL3NQiR5IC&pg=PT231&lpg=PT231&dq=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=ruUTnHkmKv&sig=S1qyIuNsv4HqPIHx3q__Alsusxg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQo_mW04XaAhWSJ1AKHc9IBvwQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5&f=false).*
Е. Шумская. Пособие для начинающей ведьмы

Ваше предложение мне нравится. И глагол "озаботиться" — к месту, нечастый.
Но вместо наречия "лично", которого нет в словаре русского языка XI–XVIIвв., я бы посоветовала использовать наречие [**самолично**](http://ru-eval.ru/hist/xi-xvii/Vol23s/42.pdf).

Comment: Респект за Даля и наречие!

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите соблюсти историческое правдоподобие, то так писать не стоит.
Княже - это звательный падеж от праславянского слова  *kъnędzь. 
Звательный падеж использовался только для обращения, но сходные формы могли иметь и другие косвенные падежи (процесс перехода к современным флексиям был длительным, не уверен, что его можно реконструировать полностью). Этим и объясняются случаи появления формы "княже" в некоторых текстах в косвенных падежах.

Но никогда подобной формы не имел именительный. Появление её в качестве подлежащего - следствие ранней утери звательного падежа в русском и ошибочной интерпретации звательной формы как исходной не слишком грамотными авторами. Нечто подобное сейчас происходит со словами "господи", "человече", "боже" и некоторыми другими, которые в массовом понимании утратили связь с формой звательного падежа и выступают зачастую как подлежащее: *"Нам Боже даровал, как хлеб насущный, источник Света..."* ([Фейсбук](https://www.facebook.com/stefaniadanilova/posts/823154394391911)), но это совершенно против грамматики.

*И в дополнение.*

*Тут упоминалась совершенно невероятная форма "княж".

Даю небольшую справку.В отношении чередования Г/Ж/(Д)З: Князь-Княгиня-Княжич.
Исторически там общий корень, восходящей к древнескандинавскому "конунг" - то есть корневое Г. Но по правилам первой и второй палатализации перед гласными **переднего**  ряда (включая Ерь), Г переходит в З. Так появился "князь". В "княгине" и подобных сохранилось Г, так как исторически там было Ы - княгыня. 
Переход же Г в Ж - влияние уже третьей палатализации, которая не затронула слова, подвергшиеся первым двум.*

*О палатализациях - см. [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).*

Тысячу раз извиняюсь за глупую описку в предыдущей редакции. Тут, конечно, имелись в виду гласные **переднего** ряда.

Comment: @ Мимоходов Да-да, палатализация! Вспомнила, впала в экстаз. Утащила все три и любуюсь в уголке. Спасибище за убедительное разъяснение.!

Answer (score 1):

Форма ***княже*** иногда встречается в текстах не только  форме обращения, но не очень ясно, что она обозначает.

А на разъезде были владычни бояре; а писал грамоту **княже** Федоров дьяк Семен Иванов сын Баранов". 1498 года. http://litlife.club/br/?b=58087&p=44

И нача любити [великий князь Всеволод Ярославич] смысл уных, свет творя с ними; сии же начаша заводити й, негодовати дружины своея первыя и людем не доходити **княже** правды. http://wikii.ru/publ/chislennost_i_sostav_russkoj_druzhiny/3-1-0-1013

Comment: А каков ваш ответ?

Comment: В исторических документах  эта форма в значении И.п. вряд ли употреблялась (отдельные случаи неясны или, возможно,  ошибочны).  В исторических художественных произведениях она иногда использовалась, так что прецедента не будет. Поэтому решение за автором.